# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to fetch data from an API. I'm filtering the data into each username, so I get Kills, deaths, and headshots from each match. And I want the output to be Username and then all the kills, deaths, headshots multiplied together, but I before I can get to multiplying the data, I get this error

```
playerstats.js:45 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: matchlistResponsestats.filter is not a function
    at getmatchdata (playerstats.js:45)
```

And I don't know what is wrong

```
   async function getplayerdata1() {
    // Get current room
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const { players } = await response.json();
    return Promise.all(players.map(async (player, playerIndex) => {
      const { username, id } = player;
      const playerid = player.id
      console.log(playerid + username)
      // read user matches
      const response = await fetch(`https://api.site.com/user_profile/get_latest_matches?_=&id=${id}&page=1`);
      const matchlist = await response.json();
      return Promise.all(matchlist.map(async (match, matchIndex, array ) => {
        const { id } = match;
        // Read match stats
        const matchlistResponse = await fetch(`https://api.site.com/match/get?_=&id=${id}`);
        const matchlistResponsestats = await matchlistResponse.json();
        let matchArray = matchlistResponsestats.players.length
        async function getmatchdata() {

        for (var i = 0; i < matchArray; i++) {
          if(matchlistResponsestats.players[i].username === username) {
            matchlistResponsestats.filter((item) => item.username === username).map((item) => {
               return {
                 item: [{id: item.id, kills: item.kills, deaths: item.deaths, headshots: item.headshots}]
               }
             })
           }
        }
      }
      let playerstats = await getmatchdata()
      console.log(playerstats)

      }));
    }));
  }
  getplayerdata1()
  }
```

Update console.log( MathclistResponsestats )

```
{id: 1862369, region_id: 0, country_id: 210, map_id: 3, flags: 0, …}
{id: 1855913, region_id: 0, country_id: 57, map_id: 5, flags: 0, …}
{id: 1856079, region_id: 0, country_id: 210, map_id: 4, flags: 0, …}
```

and so on

Comment: is `matchlistResponsestats` an array or object?

Comment: You're using `matchlistResponsestats.players` and also `matchlistResponsestats.filter`. I suspect you wanted `matchlistResponsestats.players.filter` in that second case. It's impossible for an array deserialized from JSON and not subsequently modified to have a `players` property on it, so I suspect `matchlistResponsestats` is a non-array object with a `players` property, which is an array.

Comment: Can you please log the value of `matchlistResponsestats ` and update that in question for reference?

Comment: In addition to what T.J. said, that `getmatchdata` function has no need to be `async`, and probably you should omit the function wrapper altogether since you're calling it only once anyway.

Comment: Also, you're not doing anything with the result of your `.map()` and you're not returning anything from `getmatchdata()`.